# IE 11 missing iFrame [UPDATE] URL issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, internet-explorer-11

Inside "a.aspx" code basically looks like this:

```
...
<iframe id="b.aspx" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src=""></iframe>
...
```

The iframe has empty SRC and runat="server", and in codebehind (C#) we do something like this:

```
idOfIFrame.Attributes["src"] = "..."
```

The problem is that there is no iframe. In the the view source, it is clearly visible, that we have a "valid" src url, added by the codebehind. But the page where the iframe is is empty.

It ran all right for months / years. Until the user upgraded the IE11.

I had IE 11.0.9600.18097 11.0.25 (KB3100773) and the user has IE 11.0.9600.18314            11.0.31 (KB3154070). Seems like this is might be causing the issue, because I upgraded and now I am able to reproduce the missing iframe on my dev machine.

I took time to play with the URL a little bit, and I opened up the inside small iframe in a new browser tab. Hit enter, still empty. Where I should have code, there is nothing.

I have this in the aspx file:

```
<div>
<asp:GridView>
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<itemtemplate>
<table>
...
```

In the old IE version, it rendered as:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <table></table>
 </div>
</div>
```

In the new IE version, it renders as:

```
<div>
 <div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Any idea what the issue could be ?
I can simultaneously open up the same page on 2 computers (all the same compatibility settings and all that) and the other one works, and mine doesn't.

[UPDATE]

I found out that this is a URL issue. 
I am building the URL in C# like this:

```
ifr.Attributes["src"] = "../../xyz.aspx?Module=ToDo&Allow=0&isOk=" + isOk
```

The view source shows this:

```
"../../xyz.aspx?Module=ToDo&amp;Allow=0&amp;isOk=" + isOk
```

Seems like this version of IE does not recognize `&amp;` in the URL-s anymore. Honestly, I think is a MS IE 11 bug. My variable is defaulted to zero, instead of the ID that is a URL QueryStringParameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted above, I found the issue (see [UPDATE] section)

My temporary fix is this simple:

```
document.getElementById('<%=ifr.ClientID%>').src = document.getElementById('<%=ifr.ClientID%>').src;
```

Yes I added a JS thing which reloads the iFrame. Basically the Iframe is loaded twice right now (once with ID zero, and once with the correct ID), which is not the most beautiful way to fix this, but I am pretty sure that this is an MSIE11 issue, and this will do it for now.